# HTTP client can't fetch a page while other tools (wget/curl) can

Tags: http, go

The following code in Go can't fetch page, it gets 404 error, while code in another language (php+curl) has no issues with this page. What is a reason of such behaviour?

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := http.Client {}
    req, err  := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://myhresschoolofmusic.com/", nil)

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)
}
```

Output of this code

```
&http.Response{
Status:"404 Not Found", 
StatusCode:404, 
Proto:"HTTP/2.0",
 ProtoMajor:2, 
ProtoMinor:0, 
Header:http.Header{"Content-Length":[]string{"1245"}, 
"Content-Type":[]string{"text/html"}, 
"Date":[]string{"Wed, 20 Jan 2021 06:44:22 GMT"}, 
"X-Powered-By":[]string{"ASP.NET"}}, 
....
```

Comment: The service rejects requests with the net/http default user agent.  Add a User-Agent header to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that page is very picky about `User-Agent` header and rejects Go `net/http` default value `Go-http-client/1.1`. With browser-like user agent value like:

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://myhresschoolofmusic.com", nil)
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36")
```

it works just fine.